# Chmod is not working as expected

Tags: permissions, chmod

When i am about to change my file permission like this

```
 $ sudo chmod a+x *.*
```

This error appear

```
 chmod: cannot access ‘*.*’: No such file or directory
```

And when i want to change the permission of every single file in a directory with

```
 $ sudo chmod a+x directory/*
```

The same error appear

```
 chmod: cannot access ‘directory/*’: No such file or directory
```

When i try the same command in other directory it works but under this directory /var/www/html it does not work but even when i change the permission file by file to a+x when i run

```
 ls
```

A permission error appear

```
 ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add `namei -mo /var/www/html` command output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file extension in Linux is nothing special, it is just a part of the file name. The file globbing of the the shell uses `*` for all characters so you can just use `chmod a+x *` instead of `.`

Comment: This is right if in folder are not present file like foo.bar, and it seems that command `sudo chmod a+x directory/*` fails due to wrong directory or the directory is empty. @UweBurger if you want you can add this comment in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `ls` issue sounds like you might not have sufficient privileges on the directory.  As https://stackoverflow.com/a/15800917/3501748 states: directories need the execute permission set in order to see their contents.

`cd` back a level and see what the permissions are on the directory you have just come from.  `sudo` does not give you any rights to access a folder if root does not have any rights to that folder.  Maybe `sudo -u <username>` might help.

If you need to recurse through the directory tree below your starting point use `chmod -R`.

Comment: Probably ls command fail because folder is executable (user can cd in it) but not readable by the user.

Comment: You should advise user to be careful using `chmod -R`, this command is dangerous and can break system if it is executed with wrong parameter and sudo right.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to acknowledge existing answers:

- As UweBurger says one uses `*` for a general wildcard in Ubuntu (or, I believe, Unix in general). (Is it possible that `directory` in your example is empty, causing the error `chmod: cannot access ‘directory/*’: No such file or directory`?)
- As northern-bradley suggested, one can use the `R` flag in `chmod` to make it traverse the tree recursively, changing the permissions of everything under your current point. That is, use `chmod -R directory`, or if you lack privileges `sudo chmod -R directory` (however, do be sure not to inadvertently change permissions on system files when using [`sudo` to `chmod`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#chmod_with_sudo); your own user simply lacks privileges to do so, making the first variant safer).

However, I'd like to add that you might not want to change directories' permissions in the same manner you do files'. As explained in the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions), the read (`r`) permission for directories means being able to view its contents (such as using `ls`), the write (`w`) permission allows a user to create/remove files in it, and the execute (`x`) permission to `cd` inside. There's a great answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/91938/294963) suggesting a method to distinguish between files and directories when applying new permissions recursively. The variant using `xargs` is [supposedly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896808/find-exec-cmd-vs-xargs). You might wish to add the `r` flag to `xargs` to avoid an error in case `find` returns nothing, and if you need `root` privileges you should use `sudo` for both halves of the pipe (again, exercise care when `chmod`ing as `root`), so that would be:

> sudo find [path/to/dir] -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -0r chmod [desired-dir-permissions]
>
> sudo find [path/to/dir] -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0r chmod [desired-file-permissions]

where `[desired-*-permissions]` can be given [explicitly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#chmod_with_Numbers) (`777`) or [using letters](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#chmod_with_Letters) (like `a+x`).